# run psexec as admin mode win2008 with UAC mode 4 (powershell maybe?)

Tags: powershell, uac, psexec

I am trying to run the following command in cmd with admin mode:

```
psexec -u mydomain\myuser -p mypass net time /set /domain:%USERDOMAIN% /y
```

I am getting: 'net exited with error code 2'

this is only working when i change UAC level to 3 (instead of 4)

how can resolve this problem?
how can i sync the clock of the server?
maybe there is a powershell alternative?

I need your help

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to elevate your account with any script language you prefer. All processes are run with user rights on Win 7/Vista/Win 2008 hosts until you elevate them to admin. Elevating rights will require a script.

You can use the following WMI short sample code with the proper "impersonationLevel=Impersonate" syntax, where "Impersonate" is replaced with "admin" if you sign your code (which can be a pain):

```
' Enumerate cimv2 on remote host strComputer
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & _
"{impersonationLevel=Impersonate}!//" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
```